# Utility to format a Bison/Yacc grammar file nicely?

Tags: parsing, yacc, bison, pretty-print

Hello there: Do you folks know of any GNU/Linux utility to format a Bison grammar file, containing C code, nicely? I'm thinking of something along the lines of GNU Indent, but designed to beautify grammar files rather than C code.

Comment: I'll point you to a related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1150301/631423

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's also an answer about [Indenting in VIM with all the files in Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218528/indenting-in-vim-with-all-the-files-in-folder/3218571#3218571), so if vim does a good enough job for you, you could use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tool for indenting - but it will take your bison file and generate a nice railroad diagram for you - 
http://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui

example of it being used:
http://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/#syntax

Comment: Actually a Bison grammar must be converted first. This can be accomplished by starting at http://bottlecaps.de/convert/