# Indenting in VIM with all the files in Folder

Tags: vim, indentation

I have a folder containing hundreds of TTL (TeraTermLanguage) files. 
Now I wanted indent all these files.

I have created teraterm.vim for indentation and I open a file using VIM and do "gg=G" and whole file gets indented properly.

But is there any way, where I can indent all the files in folder.

I wanted to do with help of Shell. But in VIM I couldnt pass file indent command as the argument to VIM.

Please suggest which is the best way I can do indentation to all the files in VIM.

Comment: this is a bit confusing...
which Shell are you using?

If you are using something like bash (and using the answer from amphetamachine below), the following should work:

for file in *.ttl *TTL ; do vim -s indentme.src $file ; done

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Much simpler than scripting vim from the bash command line is to use vimscript from inside of vim (or perhaps a much simpler one-liner for scripting vim from the command line).  I personally prefer using the arg list for all multi-file manipulation.  For example:

```
:args ~/src/myproject/**/*.ttl | argdo execute "normal gg=G" | update
```

- `args` sets the arglist, using wildcards (`**` will match the current directory as well as subdirectories)
- `|` lets us run multiple commands on one line
- `argdo` runs the following commands on each arg (it will swallow up the second `|`)
- `execute` prevents `normal` from swallowing up the next pipe.
- `normal` runs the following normal mode commands (what you were working with in the first place)
- `update` is like `:w`, but only saves when the buffer is modified.

This `:args ... | argdo ... | update` pattern is very useful for any sort of project wide file manipulation (e.g. search and replace via `%s/foo/bar/ge` or setting uniform `fileformat` or `fileencoding`).

(other people prefer a similar pattern using the buffer list and `:bufdo`, but with the arg list I don't need to worry about closing current buffers or opening up new vim session.)

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, 
This is simply great way of doing. Also this is very helpful in many other cases. 
Even though I was able to do using script, this is much faster. 

Well I have around 900 files which I had to modify. Only hiccup i faced is every time it fills up the screen with file names, I have to press spacebar, so that it can take up next set of files.

Comment: If it's getting in your way, you should be able to avoid the "--More--" prompt and hitting space every screen by a liberal application of `:silent`.  E.g. `:argdo silent execute "normal gg=G" | silent update`

Comment: +1 and @nicholasa.evans I would move/copy the contents of that comment into the actual answer (but that is just me)

Comment: @nickolas a. evans, This is pretty impressive. There is still so much to learn, even after 10 years of using vim!

Comment: Such answers always make me believe I'm so noob to vim even after using it for almost 7 years! +1 and :( .

Comment: @nicholasa.evans This doens't seem to work for me in Neovim. The syntax highlighting is disabled by default with argdo, so the resulting reindentation is messed up. Is there an easy way to enable syntax with your above command or through a setting?

Answer (score 12):

Open up a terminal. Type:

```
$ vim -w indentme.scr foo.c
```

Then, type this exactly (in command mode):

```
gg=G:wq
```

This will close vim, saving the process of indenting all lines in the file to a Vim script called `indentme.scr`.

**Note:** `indentme.scr` will contain a record of all key commands typed, so when you are done indenting the file, don't spend a lot of time using the arrow keys to look around the file, because this will lead to a much larger script and will severely slow down batch operations.

Now, in order to indent all the lines in a file, just type the following command:

```
$ vim -s indentme.scr unindented-file.c
```

Vim will flash open-shut (if you're on a fast computer and not editing a huge file), indenting all lines, then saving the file in-place.

Unfortunately, this will only work on one file at a time, but you can scale the functionality easily using `sh`'s `for` loop:

```
for filename in *.ttl ; do
    vim -s indentme.scr "$filename"
done
```

**Note:** This will save-over any file. Unless `set bk` is in your `~/.vimrc`, don't expect a backup to be saved.

Answer (score 3):

I went off of amphetamachine's solution. However, I needed to recursively search through multiple directories.  Here's the solution that I used:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.ttl' -exec vim -s indentme.scr "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from the above answers I would like to make this complete.
I will start from the scratch so that a beginner can understand.

**Step-1**
Install astyle (tool used for formatting ) by using the following command
Open up a terminal. Type:

```
sudo apt-get install astyle
```

**Step-2** Make sure you have vim installed on your system.Run the below commands from the directory in which your code files are.The below command will create a script that we intend to run recursively so as to beautify each and every file in our directory.(as mentioned in the above answer)

```
vim -w indentme.scr foo.c
```

**Step-3** Then, type this exactly (in command mode) and press enter

```
:%!astyle
```

**Step-4**Then type this exactly (in command mode) and press enter

```
:wq
```

**Step-5** Last run this recursively by the following command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec vim -s indentme.scr "{}" \;
```

All your cpp files will be formatted properly.