# external lisp code indenter

Tags: lisp, indentation

I have some **lisp/scheme-like** code which I want to indent.
I searched for tools like GNU `indent`, but I could not find any 
command-line utility/script. There are lots of them available for 
C/C++/Java ,but somehow I am unable to find any for lisp/scheme, 
can anyone please let me know of any such indentation tools if available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `emacs` in batch mode. For example, you could create a file `indent.el`

```
(defun my/indent-file (fPath)
  (let ((buffer (find-file fPath)))
    (message (concat "indenting file " fPath))
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer buffer)))

(mapcar 'my/indent-file argv)
```

and then call emacs like this to indent a bunch of files (note that it will work for any language emacs can recognize and knows how to indent):

```bash
emacs --load indent.el --batch MY_LISP_FILES
```

See e.g. [this page](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_idioms_batch.html) to get more information about idiomatic ways to use `emacs` for batch processing.

**Edit**

Here is a one-liner which works only on one file but doesn't use the `argv` variable (beware: the arguments order is important):

```
emacs --batch MY_FILE --eval '(indent-region (point-min) (point-max))' -f 'save-buffer'
```

Comment: I tried this, got error `Symbol's value as variable is void: argv`. I am not an `emacs` user and not sure how to debug this. I see many suggestions like these - i.e, to use `emacs` - is this the **only** way?. Are there no external utils? (sometimes I feel I should have been a `emacs` user!) Thanks.

Comment: @vyom This error is strange since `argv` should be a built-in variable... Maybe you could try replacing `argv` by `command-line-args-left`. Also, did you call emacs with the correct arguments `--load script-file` and `--batch`?
And yes, you should definitely be an emacs user, but it's not too late ;)

Comment: yes, I used the options as given. On changing `argv` to `command-line-args-left`, I get other errors, but indentation is not happening. Does this have to do with `emacs` version? I have `21.3.1` on Redhat.

Comment: @vyom Yes, it might have to do with your emacs version. See my edit for a one-liner which doesn't use the `argv` variable but only works on one file.

Comment: no, this is not working either! :(, I get `End of file during parsing`. I am OK with 1 file also.

Comment: @vyom Oops: my fault! I had an extra opening paren. It should be fixed in my edit. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

If you use vim, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218528/indenting-in-vim-with-all-the-files-in-folder) post should give you a way to run vim's auto indent command on all files. And if you want (IMO) really good indenting of lisp files in vim, I recommend loading slimv and the swank server before running that command.

Comment: I found many examples to do from within `vim/emacs`, but I specifically wanted an external utility - which I can run in batch mode. I understand that `vim`, and `emacs` have batch mode - but a separate utility will be good.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://nkmathew.github.io/yasi-sexp-indenter/) my ambitious attempt at creating a decent batch mode indenter codenamed yasi(yet another s-expression indenter). If for some reason it doesn't win you over(it's about `800` lines), you can fallback to `lispindent2.lisp` which is basically Dorai's original indenter(`lispindent.lisp`) with some tweaks here and there. `lispindent2.lisp` is a batch mode indenter that is as lean as the original one(added about 65 lines) but still indents beautifully.

Comment: Thanks, now I have moved away [completely] from anything like `lisp`!, but at that time when I was working on it, I finally wrote one myself in C! :-/. Has *yasi* been available , I would definitely use it!. Now that I know, I will bookmark it :)

Comment: I had a feeling you weren't doing anything Lispy anymore. You're not alone in that. I'd like to see your `C` version(anyone who can make a working text munging program in `C` is a badass in my books.)

Comment: I have cut-pasted the relevant parts to this gist - https://gist.github.com/aniruddha-a/7983060 ; not sure if this is generic enough for all needs, but back then this was all that I needed, HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Dorai Sitaram has the `scmindent.scm` and `lispindent.lisp` scripts on [this website](http://evalwhen.com/scmindent/index.html) that will work for that purpose. They were originally intended to let you indent Lisp code in vi.