# How to correctly indent Django template code automatically?

Tags: python, django, indentation

I am taking care of an old Django project and discovered that most of the templates are not indented correctly (random spaces in each line, sometimes tabs instead of spaces, etc). I feel comfortable with two-space indentation.

I never had this kind of problem and would like a solution (a script, library, doesn't matter) which would take care of this. Note that I do not want something that formats the HTML before sending it to the client but I want to format the local files that are used for templating.

I tried to use BeautifulSoup and its `prettify` function - however, it does not let you change the indentation level (although you can always modify it) and the indentation made for some template tags (`{% example %}`) was incorrect.

Comment: Sublime Text has a "reindent" function that should be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks @mevius. I was looking for something that I can apply to multiple files at once - opening one by one with an editor seems like a daunting task.

Comment: Perhaps this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218528/indenting-in-vim-with-all-the-files-in-folder