# Indent multiple files with vim from command line

Tags: linux, vim, command-line

I am trying to indent multiple files with `vim`. Can I do this without manually opening the files one by one? The following is not working:

```
for f in `ls`; do vim -c 'gg=G' -c 'wq' $f; done
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218528/indenting-in-vim-with-all-the-files-in-folder

Comment: This isnt command line, shell prompt right?

Comment: @SibiCoder, yes, shell.

Comment: You can edit the question for better understanding. I thought you are executing in Vim's command line :P edit the question :)